# PHP Laravel Framework - How to use appzcoder crud-generator with locale

Tags: php, laravel, crud-admin-generator

I am new with PHP Laravel framework using appzcoder crud-generator, found here https://github.com/appzcoder/crud-generator.

It successfully generates views/models/controllers for given table and working fine. But when using the options `--localize` and `--locales`, it still working, but I did not see any difference with respect to locale.

Can any body suggest how to make it work with two languages `en (english/ltr)` and `ar (arabic/rtl)`, and how to access views with specific locale, i.e. may be through routes?